# Can i use Spring Boot Admin Server as rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-restdocs, spring-boot-admin

I have succesfully configured sba and and admin clients. Is it possible to use sba as a rest provider? Is there any documentation for using it as api?

Answer (score 1):

There is no docs on the api, but yes you can use it, but I guess you need to look in the sources to use it.